# MSXML2.XMLHTTP60 request fails for standard user but works for local administrator

Tags: xml, ms-access, vba

I've written a function for our Microsoft Access 2010 database/application to retrieve some data from a supplier's web service.  It's a pretty simple operation and works fine under my login (a local administrator account) but doesn't work for any users who are standard users on their PCs.

```
  Dim http As New XMLHTTP60
  Dim strRequestData As String

  'Build the request
  strRequestData = _
    "<xml><somedata></somedata></xml>"

  'Send request
  http.Open "POST", "https://oursupplier.com/access/access.htm", True
  http.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  http.Send "XML=" & strRequestData

  'Wait for response
  Dim I As Integer
  Do Until http.ReadyState = 4 'Completed

    'Only wait 500*40 (20 seconds)
    I = I + 1

    If I > 40 Then
      MsgBox "Operation timed out (20 seconds)."
      http.abort
      Exit Function
    End If

    Sleep 500
    DoEvents
  Loop

  If http.status = 200 Then
    ReturnValue = http.responseText
  Else
    On Error Resume Next 'Don't error if we can't read a property

    MsgBox "Request failed - HTTP status '" & http.status & " " & http.StatusText & "'"

    LogMessage "logfile.txt", "*** Request failed ***"
    LogMessage "logfile.txt", "HTTP Status: " & http.status
    LogMessage "logfile.txt", "HTTP Status Text: " & http.StatusText
    LogMessage "logfile.txt", "Request: " & "XML=" & strRequestData
    LogMessage "logfile.", "Response: " & http.responseText
    On Error GoTo 0
  End If

  'Clean up
  Set http = Nothing
```

The error logged is:

```
  14/07/2016 9:04:08 am *** Request failed ***
  14/07/2016 9:04:08 am HTTP Status: 12004
  14/07/2016 9:04:08 am HTTP Status Text:
  14/07/2016 9:04:08 am Request: <xml><somedata></somedata></xml>
  14/07/2016 9:04:08 am Response:
```

12004 means ERROR_INTERNET_INTERNAL_ERROR (An internal error has occurred.)

Why would the permissions of the user have a bearing on an "internal error"?  I'm guessing it's not talking about an HTTP response code of 500?

Answer (score 0):

I changed XMLHTTP60 to **Server**XMLHTTP60.  This class works without needing local admin rights.

I have no idea why this fixes the problem.

```
Dim http As New ServerXMLHTTP60
```